# Blueimp Fileupload after Ajax request not fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, blueimp

I am using the Blueimp file upload plugin in a table. Each row has in image and can be changed by uploading an image in the row itself. I initialize the plugin just the way as defined in the docs. After uploading the image, the image is processed on the server and the path to the image is stored in a database. When all goes well an ajax request is executed to update the table.

This also works fine, but when I want to upload another image again, the plugin is not executed. What could be the issue of this and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was fired onchange of a file input, after the uploaded image was processed an ajax-call rebuild the DOM of the table. And after rebuilding the DOM the plugin must be initiated again to be applicable of the newly generated file input elements.